# Use translucent property and view move down ward

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am using `NavigationBar` back ground pic but the view is not good which i have show in this picture.Also for this solution i have used (`self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO`) but after this view going down ward i have many solution for this and the[image] same thing is repeated for stoping view (`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone`) but after that my problem was same.kindly tell me any one that how i control my view.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to get the top layout height,

Example :

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
     if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)])
    {
            float y = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run whether on device or simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of view you are using, this has worked for me with TableViews, ScrollViews and CollectionViews:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: thanks every body i have solved this problem.I just delete navigation controller and then add it again it works fine